# Stars color detection using python

Tags: python-3.x, colors, anaconda, detection, starscream

I am working on an algorithm that detects new objects in an image of stars. additionally I want my algo to detect if the stars have altered with age as they change their colors with time. hottest appear to be blue where as coldest appear to be red. Is there any way that you guys suggest to implement this using python?
I personally think of two ways.

1. get the vector values of image per point pixel and compare
2. simply apply operations on image to detect the color and then somehow compare with the source image.
   i dont know how do do either of these
   help me

Answer (score 1):

Hello ı worked about color detection in python,I suggested to you cv2 and numpy library for this.Also you can look this link.That is give you clue you how to color detection and you can change the color
link:https://github.com/mustafakendiguzel/OpenCv-Python-Color-Detection-Image-Processing-